# CAML filtered list views - filter more than one nested level?

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, caml, query

do you know if it's possible with CAML to write a SharePoint list view filter query to retrieve a user that is a member of a group which in turn is a member of another group i.e. nested groups?

I've got it working so that the column "Members" is filtered to show users that are members of a security group:

```
<Or>
 <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
     <FieldRef Name="Members" />
 </Membership>
 <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Members" />
      <Value Type="Integer">
           <UserID/>
      </Value>
 </Eq>
</Or>
```

This gives me the list items where the currently logged in user is a member of a security group in the "Members" list column.

However, I'm unable to get it to go down a level further. Use case is there're users that are members of a security group which itself is a member of another security group and that one is the actual value of a field in the "Members" list column.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a nested Or. The basic syntax is:

```
<Or>
    <!--test 1-->
    <!--test 2-->
</Or>
```

Which is what you have, but either or both of test 1 and 2 can themselves be a logical join (i.e. Or or And), so

```
<Or>
    <!--your third test goes here-->
    <Or>
        <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
            <FieldRef Name="Members" />
        </Membership>
       <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Members" />
            <Value Type="Integer">
                <UserID/>
            </Value>
        </Eq>
    </Or>
    <!--or here-->
</Or>
```

So a CAML query can be either a single test at the top level or a logic join at the top level, and the logical join can join only 2 tests, but each of those tests can be a logical join too, and you can nest them as deeply as you like.